# Django - Settings : sensitive settings and different environments (dev, prod, staging). What is the recommended way to do this

Tags: django, django-settings

I am using django version 2.1.7:

I have read a lot of article and questions about this. I found people using various methods.

```
Approches used in the general are:
1) setting environmental variables
2) multiple settings
3) load configuration variables from a file like using django-environ etc
```

`Approach 1:` I will not be using, because i dont want to use environmental variables to store variables.

`Approach 3:` uses 3rd party library and sometimes they may not be maintained any more. But if there is any standard way to do this i am fine.

`Approach 2:` Here i am not sure how to store the sensitive data seprately.

So can someone guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a combination of all:

- When launching gunicorn as a service in systemd, you can set your environment variables using the conf file in your .service.d directory:

  ```
  [Service]
  Environment="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings.production"
  Environment="DATABASE_NAME=MYDB"
  Environment="DATABASE_USER=MYUSER"
  Environment="DATABASE_PASSWORD=MYPASSWORD" 
  ...
  ```
- That file is fetched from S3 (where it is encrypted) when the instance is launched. I have a startup script using aws-cli that does that.
- In order to be able to run management commands, e.g. to migrate your database in production, you also need these variables, so if the environment variables aren't set, I fetch them directly from this file. So in my settings, I have something like this:

  ```python
  def get_env_variable(var_name):
      try:
          return os.environ[var_name]
      except KeyError:
          env = fetch_env_from_gunicorn()
          return env[var_name]

  def fetch_env_from_gunicorn():
      gunicorn_conf_directory = '/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service.d'
      gunicorn_env_filepath = '%s/gunicorn.conf' % (gunicorn_conf_directory,)
      if not os.path.isfile(gunicorn_env_filepath):
          raise ImproperlyConfigured('No environment settings found in gunicorn configuration')

      key_value_reg_ex = re.compile(r'^Environment\s*=\s*\"(.+?)\s*=\s*(.+?)\"$')
      environment_vars = {}
      with open(gunicorn_env_filepath) as f:
          for line in f:
              match = key_value_reg_ex.search(line)
              if match:
                  environment_vars[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
      return environment_vars

  ...

  DATABASES = {
      ...
      'PASSWORD': get_env_variable('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
      ...}
  ```

  Note that all management commands I run in my hosted instances, I need to explicitly pass `--settings=myapp.settings.production` so it knows which settings file to use.
- Different settings for different types of environments. That's because things like `DEBUG` but also mail settings, authentication settings, etc... are too different between the environments to use one single settings file.
  I have *default.py* settings in a *settings* directory with all common settings, and then *production.py* for example starts with `from .default import *` and just overrides what it needs to override like `DEBUG = False` and different `DATABASES` (to use the above mechanism), `LOGGING` etc...

With this, you have the following security risks:

- Anyone with ssh access and permissions for the systemd directory can read the secrets. Make sure you have your instances in a VPN and restrict ssh access to specific IP addresses for example. Also I only allow ssh with ssh keys, not username/password, so no risk of stealing passwords.
- Anyone with ssh access to the django app directory could run a shell and `from django.conf import settings` to then read the `settings`. Same as above, should be restricted anyway.
- Anyone with access to your storage bucket (e.g. S3) can read the file. Again, this can be restricted easily.